# Issue with creating a Postgres RDS in Cloudformation Template

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following YML in my cloud formation template:

```
MyDB:
  Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
  Properties:
    DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceName
    DBName: !Ref DBName
    AllocatedStorage: "100"
    DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceType
    Engine: "postgres"
    EngineVersion: "9.6.2"
    MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
    MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
    PubliclyAccessible: false
    StorageType: standard
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !Ref PrivateAccess
    MultiAZ: true
  DeletionPolicy: "Snapshot"
```

It is failing due to "The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-7c99881b and the EC2 security group is in vpc-34ef9c4d"

I tried adding a DBSecurityGroup

```
DbSecurityByEC2SecurityGroup:
  Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup"
  Properties:
  GroupDescription: "Ingress for Amazon EC2 security group"
  DBSecurityGroupIngress:
    - EC2SecurityGroupId: !Ref PrivateAccess
```

and changed the MyDB:

```
      DBSecurityGroups:
    - !Ref DbSecurityByEC2SecurityGroup
```

but it now says "EC2 security group sg-7debfb0c is in a different VPC vpc-34ef9c4d. It cannot be authorized to RDS DBSecurityGroup dbsecuritybyec2securitygroup-1whvh0xi93cke for VPC vpc-7c99881b."

vpc-34ef9c4d is the vpc i am wanting this RDS in, how do I specify which VPC the DB should be located in?

Updated Template:

```
MyDB:
  Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
  Properties:
    DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceName
    DBName: !Ref DBName
    AllocatedStorage: "100"
    DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBInstanceType
    Engine: "postgres"
    EngineVersion: "9.6.2"
    MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
    MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
    PubliclyAccessible: false
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
    StorageType: standard
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !Ref PrivateAccess
    MultiAZ: true
  DeletionPolicy: "Snapshot"

myDBSubnetGroup:
  Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
  Properties:
    DBSubnetGroupDescription: "description"
    SubnetIds:
      - !Ref PrivateSubnet
```

Comment: According to  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups, If you set VPCSecurityGroups, you must not set DBSecurityGroups, and vice versa. You should use AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup.

Comment: Yes, I replaced the VPCSecurityGroup with DBSecurityGroup when I tried adding a new DBSecurityGroup..  the !Ref PrivateAccess is a reference to a AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup I also created in the same template

Comment: Use DBSubnetGroupName. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsubnetgroupname. That determines the VPC. If nothing is specified, RDS is created in the default vpc

Comment: Worth reading http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html

Comment: DBSubnetGroupName is what I was missing! Thanks!

Comment: Can you mark that as the answer?

Comment: I can mark a comment as an answer.. answer question and i'll accept yours

Comment: In my case error comes up after using `ec2:SecurityGroup` insted of `VPCSecurityGroup` 
RollingBack at ```DB subnet group 'DBSubnetGroup' does not exist. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: DBSubnetGroupNotFoundFault; Request ID: bf7a2efb-a57a-4b5a-bf9b-847dda8594d9)```
Even if i am creating `DBSubnetGroup`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use DBSubnetGroupName (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsubnetgroupname). That determines the VPC. If nothing is specified, RDS is created in the default vpc

Comment: I have defined the dbsubnetgroup but still same error occures.----> 
`dbsubnetgroup = t.add_resource(
    rds.DBSubnetGroup(
        "DBSubnetGroup",
        DBSubnetGroupDescription="Subnets available for the RDS DB Instance",
        DBSubnetGroupName='DBSubnetGroup',
        SubnetIds=[Ref(db_subnet_AZ_1), Ref(db_subnet_AZ_2)],
        Tags=Tags(Client=Client, Name=Join("-", [Ref("AWS::StackName"), "DBSubnetGroup"]),),
    ))`