# The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs, cloudFormation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I want to automate the process of creating RDS. I would like to create RDS Aurora.
When deploying the application, stack cloudFormation is validated and I have an error:

> An error occurred: DatabaseCluster - The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs.

Can you say what's wrong?

I followed this post [Issue with creating a Postgres RDS in Cloudformation Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445181/issue-with-creating-a-postgres-rds-in-cloudformation-template) but this doesn't work.

Here is part of my serverless.yml file

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DatabaseCluster:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
      Properties:
        DatabaseName: name${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
        Engine: aurora
        MasterUsername: ${ssm:MasterUsername-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
        MasterUserPassword: ${ssm:MasterUserPassword-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
        Port: "3306"
        VpcSecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref VpcSecurityGroup

    ServerlessRDS:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        Engine: aurora
        DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref "DatabaseCluster"
        DBInstanceIdentifier: db-name-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.medium
        VPCSecurityGroups:
          - !Ref VpcSecurityGroup
        DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup


    VpcSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        VpcId:
          Ref: ServerlessVPC
        GroupDescription: "Allow all traffic"
        SecurityGroupEgress:
          - IpProtocol: -1
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: -1
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

    ServerlessVPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"

    myDBSubnetGroup:
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: "description"
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref ServerlessSubnetA
          - !Ref ServerlessSubnetB
    ServerlessSubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        VpcId:
          Ref: ServerlessVPC
        AvailabilityZone: "eu-west-1b"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/24"
    ServerlessSubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        VpcId:
          Ref: ServerlessVPC
        AvailabilityZone: "eu-west-1a"
        CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to add `DBSubnetGroupName` parameter to `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` Resource.

```
DatabaseCluster:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
  Properties:
    DatabaseName: name${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    Engine: aurora
    MasterUsername: ${ssm:MasterUsername-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
    MasterUserPassword: ${ssm:MasterUserPassword-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
    Port: "3306"
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref VpcSecurityGroup
    DBSubnetGroupName:
      Ref: myDBSubnetGroup
```

Also you may want to add explicit dependencies on `ServerlessSubnetA` and `ServerlessSubnetB` in `VpcSecurityGroup` Resource to kind of group resource creation by the service and to avoid any race conditions.

```
VpcSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DependsOn: 
    - ServerlessSubnetA
    - ServerlessSubnetB
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: ServerlessVPC
      GroupDescription: "Allow all traffic"
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this situation and found someone had changed the dBs VPC.

Someone had taken a snapshot and restored it to a different VPC and that obviously didn't have the Security Group needed.

This probably happened because the website talking to the database was running on a different VPC.

To resolve it, you need to make a tough decision, because at this point you may end up having to blow the whole thing away and if its part of a group of CFN templates then that could spell even more problems with domino effects.

It's probably worth you try restore the dB back to the original VPC (or change Subnet Group/VPC) where the CFN template *thinks* it lives and where the security group was created by the CFN template and then re-run the CFN template.

If this fails, for example the database version has recently been updated you might get stuck with:

> Cannot upgrade postgres from 9.6.22 to 9.6.11

At this point, the only recourse I know of is to delete the CFN stack and re-run it.